# Determine the change of the argument of the function $f(z)=z^2+1+\frac{5}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}$ as z traverses the unit circle once counterclockwise.

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Determine the change of the argument of the function $f(z)=z^2+1+\frac{5}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}$ as z traverses the unit circle once counterclockwise.

MY attempt:

By argument principle we need to fin the amount of zeroes and poles this function has in the unit circle. It has a single pole of order 2 at $z=0$. Now for the zeroes I consider the function $z^2f(z)=z^4+z^2+5z+1$ Now by Rouche's theorem, since $|z^4+z^2|<|5z+1|$ on the unit circle, we know that $f(z)$ only one zero. Thus it traverses -1 times.

IS this correct? If not, what is the mistake and what is the correct solution. If it is correct, can you improve upon my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. As an alternative, you can apply “Rouché's theorem for meromorphic functions“ (see for example [A question about Argument Principle/Rouche's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608160/a-question-about-argument-principle-rouches-theorem/608224#608224)) to $f(z)=z^2+1+\frac{5}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}$ and $g(z)= \frac 5z$: On the unit circle is
$$
 |f(z) - g(z)| = |z^2+1+\frac{1}{z^2}| \le 3 < 5 = |g(z)|
$$
so that
$$
N_f - P_f = N_g - P_g = -1 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that version of Rouche's it is certainly useful! In general Martin, your solutions have been a blessing. I am studying for my complex analysis qual and your answers (to my and others) questions are very helpful!