# Prove if $f(z)$ is meromorphic in $C$, $|f(z)|<1$, then the number of roots of $f(z)=1$ is equal to the number of poles in $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove if $f(z)$ is meromorphic in $C$, $|f(z)|<1$, then the number of roots of $f(z)=1$ is equal to the number of poles in $C$.

It can be used argument principle, but I don't know how to conclude the number of zeros which it have.

Comment: Do you mean meromorphic in the complex plane $\Bbb C$? If $|f(z)|<1$ then $f$ has no poles, so that it is an entire, bounded function, and therefore constant.

Comment: Perhaps you mean this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608160/42969 ?

Comment: Try to use Rouche's theorem for meromorphic functions.